# Python svglib.svg2rlg Bar Chart from MatPlotLib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, svg, reportlab

Given this horizontal bar chart below (**please note the modified x-axis range, which begins at 6 instead of 0**):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib 

np.random.seed(19680801)
plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,2))

people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center',
        color='green', ecolor='black')
ax.set_xlim((6,14)) #THIS IS THE KEY ISSUE
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
plt.yticks(size=10)

ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?',size=10, fontname='Arial')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('image.svg')
```

When I attempt to add the resulting SVG to reportlab via svglib, it works fine if I do not modify the x-axis range. However, if I add the resulting chart with the modified range, the bars of the chart in the output PDF extend all the way to where zero would be. This is not an issue in the original output from matplotlib and does not come up at all if I use PNG, for example.

Here is what I'm using to create the PDF via ReportLab and svglib:

```
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

my_canvas = canvas.Canvas('svg_on_canvas.pdf')
drawing = svg2rlg('image.svg')
renderPDF.draw(drawing, my_canvas, 0, 40)
my_canvas.save()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a bug in svglib or reportlab dropping the clipping from the input svg.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (really just a work-around) on the matplotlib side would be to start the x range at 0 and subtract 6 from all x values, then do plt.xticks([0,2...],['6','8'...]) to label them manually.